# Why, in זימון, is it customary to change from "רבותי נברך" to "ברשות מרנן ורבנן ורבותי"?

Tags: nuschaot, bentching, zimun

Why, at the beginning of ברכת הזימון is it comon custom that the leader opens with "**רבותי** נברך" and later he continues with "ברשות **מרנן ורבנן ורבותי**" .

Why, at the beginning does he only address **רבותי**, and later he addresses **מרנן ורבנן ורבותי.**

Also why would he say "**רבנן ורבותי**" which means "**our Rabbis and My Rabbis**"? Isn't our Rabbis already inclusive of his Rabbis?

Comment: I'd say 'רבותי' is an honorary title for the other men present during the 'ברכת הזימון', whereas 'מרנן ורבנן' are referring to their actual Rabbis, whether present or not.